# Stata: Format for millions ( '000,000s' ) to three decimal places

Tags: stata

What's the format for displaying numbers in terms of millions to two decimal points?

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen millions = price * 1000
estpost su millions, detail
esttab, replace noisily  cells("count(fmt(%12.2gc) label(# Obs))sum(fmt(%12.2gc) label(Sum))") ///
noobs nomtitle nonumber booktabs  label  collabels(none) gaps f eqlabels(none)  posthead("")
```

For example, I want the code above to display 456.229 rather than 456,229,000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official Stata has no special display format for millions. You must divide by a million first, even if you do that on the fly. `di %4.3f 456229000/1e6` would work.

```
. di %4.3f 456229000/1e6
456.229
```

You cite `estpost` and `esttab`. It is a good convention to explain where user-written programs such as these come from. User-written programs may have their own extensions of Stata's display formats, but you should expect any such to be documented.

Comment: Is there a way to do that inline in the code above? For example, `sum/1e6(fmt(%4.3f)`? If I create a new variable divided by a million, the formatting for the `mean, median` and other stats will not be correct.

Comment: I don't use `estpost` etc. but I suspect that the easiest solution is to clone the variable but change the units to millions. If you convert to millions, summary statistics with the same units as the variable will be shown consistently.